# How to use axis2 with jakarta?

Tags: java, spring-boot, soapui, apache-axis, java-17

Axis2-transport-http uses javax.* and java 17 and tomcat 10 need jakarta EE API
Is it possible to use the Jakarta EE API with the Axis2 library and will migrating to Java 17 and Tomcat 10 work?

Answer (score 1):

The change in package naming from `javax.*` to `jakarta.*` is a breaking event. Different packages mean different software. The whole point of packages is to create separate distinct [namespaces](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace).

If your project depends on *any* Java EE components, then you cannot use Jakarta EE.

This transition has been known for years. So many Java EE components have been updated to support the new package names. Check for new versions of your needed components.

If stuck on the *javax.* naming, do not despair. The Jakarta implementations such as Jetty and Tomcat are continuing to develop parallel versions of their products in both package naming schemes. So you have time to wait for needed components to be eventually updated to Jakarta.

Regarding *Axis2* specifically, I found [this open ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/AXIS2-6051) asking for Jakarta support.